# Handling sync for binaries/non-text files in Perforce depot/workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce, binaryfiles

I am relatively new to Perforce and have been facing issues with handling binaries and pdf documents in the depot. I have a directory structure, which is sort of like an iOS framework with many static libraries (binaries) and CPP header files. Over time, I need to replace these static library binaries with updated versions in the depot. However, being non-text, a "Reconcile Offline Work" does not add the changed binaries to a changelist. Someone suggested the option of Checking out and checking in the binaries, although I'm not sure how that works in this case?

Comment: Reconciling your work should be fine, even for non-text file types. Something else must be going on. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use the command line client, the command:

p4 reconcile

should detect the updated/changed files and open them for edit (check them out).

I tested this by adding a pdf to Perforce, making some changes to another copy of it, then dropping this copy in to my workspace, without first checking out the file.

You can find more information about 'p4 reconcile' here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html

If you want to do this using P4V I suggest you contact Perforce Support, or ask on our forums. This is because we may need to ask you questions and get more information about your P4V version etc.

Hope this helps,
Jen.